# Quickest way to transform a distance dataframe to a distance matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with three columns and I want to find the quickest way to transform it to a distance matrix.

the dataframe is like :

```
A    |   B  |   distance_A_B
-----------------------------
a1   |  a2  |    0.3
a1   |  a3  |    0.5
a2   |  a1  |    0.3
```

And I want to have a distance matrix like this with python:

```
M[i][j] = distance(ai, aj)
```

I already have distances between a_i and a_j ! it's just about transforming the dataframe to matrix, I did it with two loops but I need to optimize my code

The expected answer for this example would be :

```
np.array([[0,0.3,0.5],[0.3,0,0],[0.5,0,0])
```

Thank you.

Comment: it's different I already have distances between a_i and a_j ! it's just about transforming the dataframe to matrix, I did it with two loops but I need to optimize my code

Comment: Show us the expected output for given sample?

Comment: So need `pivot` ?